# dynamic field name in happy.js json configuration

Tags: jquery, json

I have multiple tabs on the screen, each with their own identical, yet dynamically generated form. Each form has it's own unique ID, and each field within the form has a universally unique ID.

My question pertains to using [happy.js](http://happyjs.com/) (jquery plugin) in a dynamic way. happy.js configuration uses json to set field name and the handling as an object.

I'm trying to accomplish something like the following:

```
$('#capture'+tabname).isHappy({
    fields: {
        '#first'+tabname: {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please tell us your full name.'
        },
    }
})
```

The  '#first'+tabname is what is causing me problems. Is there a way to use a dynamic string there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You're just passing an object literal to `isHappy`, so rather than creating it in-place, create it beforehand and use `[]` syntax to create the dynamic key:

```
var tabFields = {};

tabFields[ '#first' + tabname ] = {
  required : true,
  message  : 'Please tell us your full name.'
};

$('#capture' + tabname).isHappy( { fields : tabFields } );
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I can't help you with that unless you tell us *how* it isn't working. Are you getting an error in the console? is your selector (`$(...)`) returning the elements you think it should? Posting the code as you expect it to work on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Nevermind. I had stupidly copied sample code and expected it to work with my actual code :)